# iptables - "could not open moddep file'"

Tags: debian, iptables

Updating kernel is not an option, I'm getting the following message when trying to run iptables

```
root@mail:/etc/postfix# iptables -L
    libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod.c:554 kmod_search_moddep: could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/2.6.32-5-xen-amd64/modules.dep.bin'
    iptables v1.4.14: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
    Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

UPDATE:

after running

```
root@mail:/home/admin#  sudo depmod
```

I get

```
ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/2.6.32-5-xen-amd64: No such file or directory
FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
```

and after

```
root@mail:/home/admin#  sudo modinfo ip_tables
```

I get

```
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod.c:554 kmod_search_moddep: could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/2.6.32-5-xen-amd64/modules.dep.bin'
ERROR: Module alias ip_tables not found.
```

It looks like kernel update is a must.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you recently upgrade the kernel on this installation? Typically iptables is built into the kernel and by default is not an external module (typically - I'm sure there are plenty of situations where that is not the case).

Try the depmod command to have the module load order recalculated; it will fix this issue on occasion:

```
 sudo depmod
```

You will need to reboot after running depmod for it to have an impact. If you get an error, please update your question with it.

Then see if `ip_tables.ko` is present at all:

```
 sudo modinfo ip_tables
```

If it's not loaded, try loading it:

```
 sudo modprobe ip_tables
```

Lastly, as a potentially valuable data point, see what iptables related kernel modules are in use with this command, and update your question with the details.

```
 cat /proc/net/ip_tables_matches
```

If it is just not found, try to see if the file is on the system:

```
 find / -name "ip_tables.ko"
```

If it's not, I believe you will have to at a minimum rebuild (or reinstall from packages) the kernel modules for your kernel release.

Comment: Did depmod fix it? Just to help anyone who stumbles by. Glad something in there worked in any case. Thanks.

Comment: It didn't fix it, it seems like the only thing left to do is to update the kernel.